# Android : Strange error when returning a simple string from doInBackground

Tags: android, string, crash, return

This is the doInBackground code in question :-

```
@Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {


        try {
            jsonArray = LoadCacheAction();

            for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject obj = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                HttpResponse httpResponse = httpResponse = ((Globals) getApplication()).SendDataApache("employeeactions", obj);;

                if (httpResponse != null) {
                    int code = httpResponse.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();
                    if ((code == 200) || (code == 201)){
                        return "ok";
                    }
                    else if ((code == 400)){
                        ((Globals) getApplication()).WriteEventLogCache(((Globals) getApplication()).TodaysDate(), "3", "1", ((Globals) getApplication()).getIdUser(), "400 - Bad request error - Clocking Action");
                        return code + "";
                    }
                    else
                        return code + "";
                }
            }

            ((Globals) getApplication()).WriteEventLogCache(((Globals) getApplication()).TodaysDate(), "3", "1", ((Globals) getApplication()).getIdUser(), "Just Testing");

            return "error";

        } catch (Exception e) {
            ((Globals) getApplication()).WriteEventLogCache(((Globals) getApplication()).TodaysDate(), "3", "1", ((Globals) getApplication()).getIdUser(), e.getMessage());
            return "conIssue";
        }
    }
```

The whole software package works perfectly right up until it hits any one of the returns.  When it does this the software crashes out completely.  I have tried taking out everything in the method and just having return "ok" and it still crashes.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why because I really cant see it at all.

Thanks

Steve

The PostExecute code :-

```
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (pDialog.isShowing())
            pDialog.dismiss();

        if (result == "ok") {
            ((Globals) getApplication()).ClearCacheFile(((Globals) getApplication()).getActionCacheFileName());
        } else {
            if (result == "error") {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Clocking Error. Try Again !!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            } else {
                if (result == "conIssue") {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Server not connected. Data will be updated when connection will be available.",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(
                            getApplicationContext(),
                            "Clocking Error. Server connection problem !!!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

This is what appears in the logs at the exact point of the crash :-

```
08-28 09:19:28.271  22411-22411/com.pe_systems.unity.unityandroid E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.pe_systems.unity.unityandroid, PID: 22411
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: View=com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView{246c3ec6 V.E..... R......D 0,0-959,128} not attached to window manager
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.findViewLocked(WindowManagerGlobal.java:396)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.removeView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:322)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.removeViewImmediate(WindowManagerImpl.java:116)
        at android.app.Dialog.dismissDialog(Dialog.java:341)
        at android.app.Dialog.dismiss(Dialog.java:324)
        at com.pe_systems.unity.unityandroid.Clocking.ClockingActivity$ServerConnectionTask.onPostExecute(ClockingActivity.java:408)
        at com.pe_systems.unity.unityandroid.Clocking.ClockingActivity$ServerConnectionTask.onPostExecute(ClockingActivity.java:357)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:636)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:177)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:653)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5254)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

08-28 09:19:28.272     546-3362/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Force finishing activity 1 com.pe_systems.unity.unityandroid/.Main.MainActivity
08-28 09:19:28.348      546-603/? I/OpenGLRenderer﹕ Initialized EGL, version 1.4

Code for ClearCaheFile :-

```
    public void ClearCacheFile(String fileName)
{
    File key = new File(getExternalCacheDir(), fileName);
    try {
        FileWriter writeKey = new FileWriter(key);

        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(writeKey);
        out.write("");
        out.close();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: @can u post your post execute method

Comment: Added the post execute code to the question.

Comment: Added the log at the point of the crash

Comment: What does this line do- `((Globals) getApplication()).ClearCacheFile(((Globals) getApplication()).getActionCacheFileName());`???

Comment: Added the code to the question.  It clears a cache file who's name is held in a variable accessed by getActionCacheFileName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion, this error occurs because the activity was destroyed when the onPostExecute(String result) method runs. To avoid this, you should cancel all running AsyncTask when the activity is detroyed.

Comment: bear with me on this - this is still all a little new to me.  Would I cancel the task and then return or cancel the task in post execute?

Comment: - Create a field in your activity to keep reference to the AsyncTask:

private YourAsyncTask mAsyncTask;

- Execute AsyncTask:

mAsyncTask = new YourAsyncTask();
mAsyncTask.execute();

- Override onDestroy() method of your activity:

public void onDestroy() {
    if (mAsyncTask != null && mAsyncTask.getStatus() ==   AsyncTask.Status.RUNNING) {
         mAsyncTask.cancel(true);
    }
}

Comment: Thank you for that - that's fixed it and I've learned something too.

Comment: i would have upvoted it but my reputation isnt high enough to let me yet